# If $\forall \epsilon >0, f(x) = \mathscr O(x^{1+\epsilon})$ is $\int^\infty \frac {1}{f(x)} = \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, definite-integrals

If $f(x)$ is positive and $\forall \epsilon >0, f(x) = \mathscr O(x^{1+\epsilon})$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, is $\int^\infty \frac {1}{f(x)} = \infty$ ?

For example, this holds for $f(x)= x \text ln(x)$ and $f(x)= x \sqrt{\text ln(x)}$.

Comment: Not for $f(x)= x\log^2(x+2)$, however.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f(x) = x\ln^2 x$, as a counter example.
(Or even $f(x) = x\ln x (\ln\ln x)^2$ if you really want to live on the edge.)

Comment: Is $x \ln x (\ln \ln x)^{1 + \varepsilon}$ good enough? Or for that matter $x \ln \ln \ln x (\ln \ln \ln x)^{1 + \varepsilon}$, etc? (I really like living on the edge)

Comment: @MCT Yes. Essentially, iterate $\ln$ as many times as you want, and put a power $1+\varepsilon$ at the end for constant $\varepsilon >0$, and you are good. I went for $x\ln x (\ln \ln x)^2$ because the antiderivative of $1/f$ has a nice closed form.

Comment: Duh, thanks. I guess it could be made into a smarter question by asking where is the edge.

Comment: @KeithMcClary For this family, the edge is at exponent $1$ for the last factor: take $f_{k, a}(x) = x\ln(x)\cdot\ln^{(2)}(x)\cdots\ln^{(k-1)}(x)(\ln^{(k)}(x))^a$. Then $1/f$ is integrable at $\infty$ (you need to start the integral at a value that makes all of it well-defined) iff $a>1$.